# Git: Is update always the same as delete then insert?

Tags: git

I'm working my way through an online course on git and one thing that they either haven't mentioned - or maybe I missed it somehow - is whether an update of a given line is ALWAYS treated as a delete and then an insert when a diff is done.

Suppose you have an existing line of code that says

```
x = 3;
```

You realize that this is incorrect and change it to say

```
x = 0;
```

You haven't deleted any lines or added any lines in your editor; you just overtyped the 3 with a zero. Is git going to treat this as if I had deleted the line entirely and then inserted a new line that says x is zero? I think it must be that way because nothing in the course has talked about updates, where an existing line is changed in the way I'm describing.

I'd just like a git expert to confirm that my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (always shown as "delete <thing> and insert <other-thing>").  But it's important to note that this is simply *how it's shown*, and that Git has built into it both line-oriented diff and word-oriented diff, plus the ability to run an *external diff* on the files.

The actual storage is done by complete snapshot: Git stores the previous version of the file as a *blob* object, and then if you changed the file, Git stores the new version of the file as a new, separate object.  (If you did not change the file at all, or if you changed it *back*, Git re-uses the existing blob that stores the correct version of the file.)  Git (re)computes the diff on the fly, whenever you ask it to compare the blob with ID *X* to the blob with ID *Y*.

At the object level, then, Git is simply a key/value data store, with the key being the object's hash ID—as computed from its content, or as delivered on a silver platter by someone saying "get me the object with hash `a1234567...`" for instance—and the value being the data content.

Down well below this level, Git *can* compact objects against each other using a delta encoding system.  This uses a modification of [xdelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta), which is not line-oriented and can be used on pure binary files.  (This depends on the Shannon entropy of the various files, so it is generally ineffective on already-compressed data.  Your binary data, if you have any, may or may not be compressed when you store it into Git.)

Comment: I'm going to take all that as a "yes" to my question ;-) I'm not particularly concerned about what goes on "under the covers" with git at this point. I'm just trying to be sure that when I merge branches, git invariably applies all deletes and inserts in the appropriate order and will NOT mangle the files in the branches. I assume git IS reliable otherwise no one would use it for long.

Comment: Ah, you might want to read some of my other answers on merge. Note that when `git merge` combines diffs (from merge base to each branch tip), it does so on a line-by-line basis. Hence you can get situations where your change is effectively canceled out by someone else's change to a different line (maybe a few lines later *they* add `x = 42`) and Git won't notice. It's always a good idea to run tests even if Git think the merge went well. But mostly it really does work pretty well.

Comment: I think I asked my question prematurely :-) The course is now explaining how merge conflicts can occur and how to handle them. Before I got to that part, I was wondering how on earth Git was going to handle a situation like the one I described where a single line was overtyped without any insert or delete unless maybe it got treated as a delete/insert. I should have been more patient and finished the course before asking :-)